# Mobile app with Cordova

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create an android app using cordova but every tutos I watched use Android Studio, But the problem is that I'dont have minimal RAM to use it, so is someone has another alternative to replace A.S??

Comment: you don't need AS to use cordova, you just need the ansroid SDK which you can install seperately.

Comment: I already tried , and followed this one : http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/Cordova_and_Eclipse_on_Windows:_Make_Android_Apps but the problem is when I build the .jar it doesnt work,Please Help!!